# Eleminate the delay when no text is set

Tags: jquery, notifications, queue, delay

I've prepared a little code snipped which works quite perfectly - except that I'd like to eliminate the pause when setting the text to an empty string (between "hello world" and "hello universe").

Can anyone figure out how? Must admit - I didn't... :-(

[Sandbox is here](http://jsfiddle.net/DCAHH/DRLgE/)

```
    <!-- Put the notificationBar somewhere in your HTML -->
    <div id="notificationBar"></div>

    /* whatever you want it to look like - keep the display: none; */
    #notificationBar {
        display: none;
        padding: 1em;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
```

The jQuery

```
    // Set it up!
    var notificationTextToggeled = 0; // Always 0
    var notificationDelay = 2000; // Whatever delay you want, in ms (1000 = 1 sec)

    // Here goes your code... intersperse it with notification messages you 
    // want to present to the user... just like below
    notificationToggle ('Hello World');
    notificationToggle ('');
    notificationToggle ('Hello Universe');
    notificationToggle ('Hello Superman');
    notificationToggle (''); 

    // This function will do all the displaying and  will keep an eye 
    // on not waving too many messages to the user in too short time:
    // Each (not empty) message text will be displayed for at least the delay time
    function notificationToggle (text) { 

        var know = $.now(); 

        if (text != $('#notificationBar').html().length && know < (notificationTextToggeled + notificationDelay ))
            $('#notificationBar').delay(notificationDelay, "fx");

        $('#notificationBar').text().length 
            $('#notificationBar').slideUp('slow'); 

         $.queue($("#notificationBar")[0], "fx", function () { 
             $(this).html(text); 
             $.dequeue(this);      
         });

         if (text) 
             $('#notificationBar').slideDown('slow'); 

         notificationTextToggeled = know;   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the text string to empty, hello universe just replaces it all together. The pause is caused by an entire rotation of ''

http://jsfiddle.net/DRLgE/11/

Comment: Nope, there *is* a need to set the message to ''. Namely in case you dont't want to show any message to your user... so, the question still is - if the messagebox is set to '' (and afterwards some other code is being executed, which actually isn't in this hello world demo), how would I delete the pause before the next *message* is shown...?

Comment: No. No box. I just found the answer thanks to Shanw Chin, who deleted his answer here for some reason though it pointed me to the right direction. Unfortunately I can self answer my question in 7 hours earliest, so I can't post the solution here right now... thank you anyway for answering